# python Error: memoryError when apply ARIMA.fit with high order q=367 for MA

Tags: python, arima

hi All stackoverflow Forum experts
i am using the software pyCharm2018.1.1

i have tried to build ARIMA model in python, my model has been identified by the parameters 
(p=0, d=0, q=367), here is the code:

```
enter code here def arima_Model_Static_PlotErrorAC_PAC(series): 
train, expctd =series , series 
arima_orders = (0, 0, 367)
model = ARIMA(series, order=arima_orders)
results_MA = model.fit(disp=-1, start_params=[.1 for i in range(1 + arima_orders[2])])
yhatList=results_MA.fittedvalues 
residuals = [expctd[i] - yhatList[i] for i in range(len(expctd))] 
mse = mean_squared_error(expctd, yhatList)
rmse = sqrt(mse)
print(results_MA.summary())
print(rmse)
```

this model is called as follow:

```
enter code here series=DataSetDiff #DataSetDiff is a series with a length of 3652 values outputResidualError=arima_Model_Static_PlotErrorAC_PAC(series)
```

an error is loaded with this high q order which is:

> Blockquote C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/109_personel/112_pyCharmArima/Presentation_Vers2_ModelOneFunct_3_5.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/109_personel/112_pyCharmArima/Presentation_Vers2_ModelOneFunct_3_5.py", line 243, in arima_Model_Static_PlotErrorAC_PAC
>       results_MA = model.fit(disp=-1, start_params=[.1 for i in range(1 + arima_orders[2])], solver='bfgs')
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 959, in fit
>       callback=callback, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 466, in fit
>       full_output=full_output)
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\optimizer.py", line 191, in _fit
>       hess=hessian)
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\optimizer.py", line 327, in _fit_bfgs
>       disp=disp, retall=retall, callback=callback)
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 916, in fmin_bfgs
>       res = _minimize_bfgs(f, x0, args, fprime, callback=callback, **opts)
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 970, in _minimize_bfgs
>       gfk = myfprime(x0)
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 300, in function_wrapper
>       return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 451, in score
>       return -self.score(params, *args) / nobs
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 583, in score
>       return approx_fprime_cs(params, self.loglike, args=(False,))
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\numdiff.py", line 202, in approx_fprime_cs
>       for i, ih in enumerate(increments)]
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\numdiff.py", line 202, in 
>       for i, ih in enumerate(increments)]
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 780, in loglike
>       return self.loglike_kalman(params, set_sigma2)
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 790, in loglike_kalman
>       return KalmanFilter.loglike(params, self, set_sigma2)
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\kalmanf\kalmanfilter.py", line 654, in loglike
>       R_mat, T_mat)
>     File "kalman_loglike.pyx", line 359, in statsmodels.tsa.kalmanf.kalman_loglike.kalman_loglike_complex
>     File "kalman_loglike.pyx", line 228, in statsmodels.tsa.kalmanf.kalman_loglike.kalman_filter_complex
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 2200, in identity
>       return eye(n, dtype=dtype)
>     File "C:\109_personel\112_pyCharmArima\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\twodim_base.py", line 186, in eye
>       m = zeros((N, M), dtype=dtype, order=order)
>   MemoryError

Process finished with exit code 1

my model is well running and forecasting until  q order MA 150 that mean(0,0,150). the error memoryError raised on the selection of q=367 as order

is any one can help me to solve this error, i have googled this error many time and i did not found a suitable solutions
Thank you for any help.

Comment: You get the memory error if q>=367?  What happens at q=150?

Comment: when q>=367 i am getting ErrorMemory, in other hand for q<=150 the model is well running

Comment: Right.  What happens for 150<q<367?

Comment: in this case i am getting the error that i have mentioned in my thread such as 
    m = zeros((N, M), dtype=dtype, order=order)
MemoryError

Comment: so for 150<q<367 you get "MemoryError" and for q>=367 you get "ErrorMemory"?

Comment: Yes Mr any order given to q greater or equal than 150 i am getting MemoryError, although my model's order is : arima_orders(0,0,367) , here is my main 2 lines codes  model = ARIMA(series, order=arima_orders) #results_MA = model.fit(disp=-1, start_params=[.1 for i in range(1 + arima_order[2])])
    results_MA = model.fit(disp=-1, start_params=[.1 for i in range(1 + arima_orders[2])], solver='bfgs')

Comment: Is it possible that you're running out of memory?

Comment: i am getting MemoryError

Comment: my hardware resources are: Lenov Corei7 with 8G RAM

Comment: Try running it keeping an eye on how much RAM you're using.  A simple moving average with 150 terms shouldn't take up too much but because you're doing it through an ARIMA model (and not just a MA model) it's possible that it's significantly less memory-efficient.

Comment: i tried to run it with q=150, and i observed the memory consumed by the model  takes about 5G from the RAM, do you advice me to use MA model instead of ARIMA? is this may solve my proble? thank you a lot for your help , really i have stayed 3 days and i did not found a true solution

Comment: It sounds like you're definitely running out of memory then.  You're currently only using a MA model since p=d=0 so you might get better results by switching to a more efficient implementation since you're not using the AR or I parts of ARIMA.  A moving average wouldn't be very hard to implement yourself.

Comment: you mean that i should extend my RAM from 8 to 32G, does it solve my problem? thank you again

Comment: I mean if you have that option, that would be one way to do it without having to change your code at all.  I don't know if it would get you all the way to 367 but it should get you a fair bit further than 150.  If you increase your RAM and you still have the same problem that would tell us something to.

Comment: Ok Mr, i will try to go to this solution extend the RAM memory, and i am going to check the result coming from my model. thank you

Comment: just i would like to ask a question, in case the extend of RAM memory does not lead me to the desired solution, what else could be done in term of modification of my code, is there any predefined functions that may help me to reduce the complexity of my model, and where this modification could take place? thank you.

Comment: If it's not that you're running out of memory, it's likely that you're overrunning a buffer somewhere.  Usually Python will give you a more useful error if that's the case though.  If more RAM gets you further but doesn't get you to the 367 that you're looking for then I would look into changing algorithms.

Comment: hi Mr. I have extended my physical RAM to 20G as a max limit that can hold my computer, and then I re-executed my model until q order equal to 180 as an example "ARIMA (0,0,180)". I had kept my computer running for hours (20) no error had been loaded, but the execution of my model had not finished and no output coming. Your suggestion about changing the program, you mean I should make some modifications in the predefined ARIMA.fit python function to get best optimization? because it is not an easy choice? if yes, can you help me trying y it?